# Linq comparing 2 dates

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-4

I am trying to compare date only. The value in table is DateTime with format 
2014-01-29 09:00:00.000. Please advise thank you

```
public static List<vwReportDate> GetDetail(string startDate, string endDate)
{
    startDate = "2014-01-28";
    endDate = "2014-01-28";

    DateTime dtStart = Convert.ToDateTime(startDate);
    DateTime dtEndDate = Convert.ToDateTime(endDate);


    var entities = new DataEntiies();
    var query = from c in entities.vwReportDate
                where c.EventCreateDate >= dtStart && c.EventCreateDate <= dtEndDate
                select c;
    return query.ToList();

}
```

Comment: Use the `Date`  property.

Comment: I noticed you implied that you're querying a table. Which ORM tool are you using? Entity Framework? Can you please update the tags in your question to reflect this?

Comment: "DateTime with format [...]" - there's no such thing. A DateTime is just a value; it doesn't inherently have a format.

Comment: @JonSkeet, I think he/she is talking about the value in his/her database table. The point is it has a non-zero time component value.

Comment: @Sam: Even if it's a value in a database field, assuming it's a datetime field it doesn't inherently have a format. It's really important to distinguish between an underlying value and an incidental textual representation. Many, many problems on Stack Overflow can be avoided with that distinction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're using Entity Framework and LINQ to EF. If that's true you can't use `DateTime.Date` property [because it's not supported](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738681%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in LINQ to EF. You have to use [`EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(myDateTime)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd395596%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) static method instead:

```
var query = from c in entities.vwReportDate
            let eventDate = EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(c.EventCreateDate)
            where eventDate >= dtStart && eventDate <= dtEndDate
            select c;
```

Answer (score 2):

My approach to this problem, which does not depend on EF, is to use "less than" for the end of the date range (after moving the end of the date range one day forward):

```
startDate = "2014-01-28";
endDate = "2014-01-28";

DateTime dtStart = Convert.ToDateTime(startDate);
DateTime dtEndDate = Convert.ToDateTime(endDate).AddDays(1);


var entities = new DataEntiies();
var query = from c in entities.vwReportDate
            where c.EventCreateDate >= dtStart && c.EventCreateDate < dtEndDate
            select c;
return query.ToList();
```

Question: why do you ignore the argument values provided by the method's caller?

Comment: What if he/she wants the query to include values that *equal* the end date? The query indicates that that's the desired behaviour. I don't think this is functionally equivalent.

Comment: @Sam: Note that I added one to the end date. If the user enters date range 2013-01-01 through 2013-12-31, the OP's criteria include date/time values such as 2013-12-31 01:00:00 by truncating the time of the database value.  My approach adds one to the range-end value, and changes the operator from '<=' to '<', so it would also include the 1 A.M. value.  To be truly equivalent, both approaches would need to truncate the range values, but since these are plainly date-only constants in the example, I omitted that from my answer.  It is, however, why I asked about the method parameters.

Comment: Sorry; I can see that you're right. I didn't notice the `AddDays` bit since your summary of what you changed only mentioned change you changed the comparison operator, which would have been incorrect by itself.

Comment: @Sam thanks for pointing that out.  I've edited the answer in the hope of making it clearer.  The main reason I posted this answer is that I've frequently seen all sorts of contortions to solve this problem, but this approach is fairly simple (albeit subject to its own limitations).

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`Date`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date.aspx) property of a `DateTime` struct to retrieve the "date" part.

> Gets the date component of this instance.

Use it in code:

```
var query = from c in entities.vwReportDate
            where c.EventCreateDate.Date >= dtStart && c.EventCreateDate.Date <= dtEndDate
            select c;
```

If you are using Entity framework (as it looks like you do), you'll have to use the [`EntityFunctions.TruncateTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd395596%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) (helper) method, because otherwise the query can't be converted.

```
var query = from c in entities.vwReportDate
            where EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(c.EventCreateDate) >= dtStart && EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(c.EventCreateDate) <= dtEndDate
            select c;
```